# Ensuring that an XOR operation on strictly positive longs only yield strictly positive longs

Tags: java, binary, binary-operators

I want to ensure that an XOR operation on strictly positive longs only yields strictly positive longs.

My question is base on the following java code:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    static Random r = new Random();

    static class Data {
        long id = Math.abs(r.nextLong());

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data {" + "id=" + id + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.add(new Data());
        }

        final String password = "don't you ever tell them";

        byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes();
        long[] passwordLongs = new long[passwordBytes.length / 8];

        for (int i = 0; i < passwordLongs.length; i++) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
            byte[] chunk = new byte[Long.BYTES];
            System.arraycopy(passwordBytes, i * Long.BYTES, chunk, 0, Long.BYTES);
            buffer.put(chunk);
            buffer.flip();//need flip
            passwordLongs[i] = buffer.getLong();
        }

        System.out.println(data);

        ListIterator<Data> encryptIterator = data.listIterator();
        while (encryptIterator.hasNext()) {
            Data next = encryptIterator.next();
            next.id = next.id ^ passwordLongs[(encryptIterator.nextIndex() - 1) % passwordLongs.length];//XOR here
        }

        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please provide an answer possibly with some theory?

Comment: How is your question related to your code?

Comment: Also, are you sure this is a useful and secure way to handle passwords? (I'm assuming it's *supposed* to be useful and secure)

Comment: @immibis: I am certainly not going to store the password a shown above. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Invariant 1: a positive integer's most significant bit is zero.
- Invariant 2: 0 XOR 0 = 0.

Conclusion: positive integer XOR positive integer = positive integer.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by invariant 1. `Long.toBinaryString(i)` always starts with **1** for positive numbers. Is this the most significant bit?

Comment: As the Javadoc explains, `This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) with no extra leading 0s`. It is impossible to get it to output a string starting with zero (unless the number itself is zero). BTW "most significant bit" pertains to the bit number 63 in a `long`.

Comment: Definitely not by converting to string. Use the test `(i & (1 << 63)) == 1`. This gives you `true` for MSB=1 and `false` for MSB=0.

Answer (score 1):

Given that longs in Java are always signed, you should make sure that every `long` from your "password" never toggles the sign bit.

That is, all your `long`s in your `password` should be like `0b0xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx`.

This weakens the "encryption" (exactly) a bit, but you should not worry much over this.

It should however be noted that unless you want to compare them being greater than 0, there is no reason doing this; the actual number will always be the same, that is, `0xff` or `0b11111111` is always the same, only its decimal representation changes according to whether you are using unsigned or signed short integer to store it (`255` and `-1` respectively).

Comment: To add, in Java 8 (1.8.x) you seem to have unsigned long as well.